# Passing array list parameter into Crystal Report using loop in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

```
public List<string>  _DELIVERYNO;
private void get_INVOICE_DATA_RPT()
{ 
  _DELIVERYNO = new List<string>();
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdDNList.Rows)
   {
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == true)
       if (row.Cells.Count >= 2 && row.Cells[2].Value != null) 
          {                          
             _DELIVERYNO.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
          }
     }
    foreach (var value in list)
     {
        get_INVOICE_DATA(value);                   
     }               
 }
```

Get the Delivery No from DataGridView and store to List.

The parameters are passed from frm1 to crystal report is OK

```
private void frmPrinINVOICE_02_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {         
   var rpt = new ReportDocument();
   rpt.Load("rptSalesInvoice_02.rpt");
   rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(userName2, passWord2, @serverName2, databaseName2);
   rpt.Refresh();
   crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
   foreach (var value in frm1._DELIVERYNO)
   {
      rpt.SetParameterValue("@DELIVERYNO", value);
   }               
   crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;       
}
```

But  the report source only keep the last data from the last query return by the last DELIVERYNO
Example: DELIVERY No: 6425,6758,6927 were passed from the frm1 . But the report only display   last query return by  DELIVERY No:6927 .

So my question how to Loop the parameter but it must keep all the data return by all passed parameters (DELIVERY No: 6425,6758,6927)

And here is the SQL store procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_IVHead_Get_INVOICE_DATA]
    @DELIVERYNO nvarchar(50)
AS
    select *
        from [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[IVHead] a
        inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[IVRecords] b
        on a.DELIVERYNO=b.DELIVERYNO        
     WHERE B.[DELIVERYNO] =@DELIVERYNO
     ORDER BY a.DELIVERYNO
```

Can we store loop result into temp table then get data out from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passed Comma Separated Values of `DELIVERY NO` from `frm1` and Add below in SQL Server function that split Separated Values

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS @Results TABLE (colA nvarchar(4000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @INDEX INT
DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(4000)

SELECT @INDEX = 1
WHILE @INDEX !=0
BEGIN

SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)
IF @INDEX !=0

SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)
ELSE
SELECT @SLICE = @STRING

INSERT INTO @Results(colA) VALUES(@SLICE)

SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)

IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK
END
RETURN
END
```

Last Alter your Stored Porcedure

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_IVHead_Get_INVOICE_DATA]
    @DELIVERYNO nvarchar(50)
AS
    select *
        from [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[IVHead] a
        inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[IVRecords] b
        on a.DELIVERYNO=b.DELIVERYNO        
        inner join DBO.Split(@DELIVERYNO,',') c 
        on B.[DELIVERYNO] = c.[colA] 
     ORDER BY a.DELIVERYNO
```

Comment: where is [colA]?

Comment: return Column Name in Split function, it depend upon you `RETURNS @Results TABLE (colA nvarchar(4000))`

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is replacing the parameter value with every iteration and leaving with the last value. Please use the following code to achieve the correct results:

Your loop:

```
foreach (var value in frm1._DELIVERYNO)
{
   rpt.SetParameterValue("@DELIVERYNO", value);
}
```

Replace it with:

```
var value = string.Join(",", frm1._DELIVERYNO);
rpt.SetParameterValue("@DELIVERYNO", value);
```

It will set the parameter with value: `6425,6758,6927`

Comment: Maybe I will edit : WHERE B.[DELIVERYNO] =@DELIVERYNO  to WHERE B.[DELIVERYNO] =IN(@DELIVERYNO)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is a part of my code. It also works